# Using MySQL JSON-field for a lot of attributes or switch to MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, laravel-5

In my web-application I have vehicles and each vehicle can have a lot of attributes (like `color`, `power`, `doors` etc). Some of these attributes are required by the system (e.g. `color` and `power`), others are optional or can be added dynamically by the user (e.g. `has_tow_coupling`).

Now I wonder wether to use a nosql-solution (in my case mongodb) or stick to mysql and make use of the json-field-type as it can be extended with new attributes easily. I use Laravel, so I can make where queries on those json-fields.

One approach would be to define the required attributes as columns and put all this dynamic stuff in a json-field called `attributes`. Another try would be, to switch to MongoDB.

On the one hand I worry about performance issues using mysql. On the other hand I don't now, if it would be good to use MongoDB for the whole application as thr rest of the database is not as complex as the vehicles-aspects.

So I have these options:

1. Stick to MySQL using JSON-field-type and virtually created columns (thanks to @JonasStaudenmeir)
2. Switch the complete application to MongoDB
3. Swap vehicles to MongoDB and use MySQL for the rest of the application

My concerns are:

1. Loss of performance when querying a table with a lot of entries (and virtually genereted columns)
2. Ease of learning/learning curve as I have never worked with NoSQL before
3. Maintainability as parts of the application use mysql while others use mongodb

What would be the best approach to handle my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934385/using-mongodb-vs-mysql-with-lots-of-json-fields). Check out [Fuwjax's very complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13020840/7152435).

Comment: As of my (not so complete) personal opinion based on my very own experience: You should see a slight increase in performance using NoSQL **if you do implement it correctly** (single-pass queries, no referencing between collections, data replication...). Maintainability is the trade-off: Updating fields in a NoSQL DB often require more work (as the Atomicity of data is not guaranteed), so you should structure your documents in a way that will benefit you the most. Learning shouldn't be a criteria here. All the time you will invest now is some time you will save tomorrow.

Comment: Regarding performance on MySQL: You can create indexes on JSON columns using virtual columns. So if you have a lot of `where('attributes->color', $color)` queries, you can create an index for this attribute.

Comment: @Brotzka - please let me know how much row you have in the vehicle table an how many rows are in the attributes table (1 Attribute = 1 row)

Comment: @BerndBuffen we are still under development but expect at least 1000 vehicles at the beginning and up to several hundred tousand. Each vehicle has a minimum of ten attributes (the required ones) but we calculate with at least 20 attributes per vehicle on average.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir a problem with your solution are the dynamically generated attributes. I as the developer can not say, which attributes will be created by the users.

Comment: I don't think you need an index for *every* attribute. After a few weeks/months of people using your app, you could analyze the custom attributes and look at the most popular ones. Then you can still add indexes for these attributes.

Comment: @Brotzka - i think that the best way is to store your data in 2 tables wit a 1:n relation. In this case you can add attributes without change the schema and it directly indexed. Your Quries can generated by mySQL to get 1 or more rows with all attribute (Pivot table).
So you have no problem to maintenance your entries via your code. 
So you can later easy store the database infos in a SOLR instance to speedup your application if necessary.